# PowerEdge 2800, PERC 6e, MD1000, 4 Member Raid 5 2TB Disks Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

When write are performed to the Virtual Disk Windows 2008 R2 crashes and reboots leaving no error enrties can be found in any LOG File.

Has anybody encountered this problem and if so is there any recommendations,

Answer (score 1):

I recommend:

- Making sure that your server has the very latest PERC 6e drivers for your exact operating system and hardware architecture.
- Ensure that your Windows server has all the latest hotfixes, updates and patches. If there are some that are not installed, make sure that you have a documented reason why they weren't. Check hidden updates to make sure.
- Update to the latest PowerEdge BIOS. That can have some effect on hardware problems. Educate yourself on what the update does and if it has known issues with any applications and services that you are running on the server.
- [Turn off auto rebooting upon a system failure.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307973) Make sure that you are seeing the "Blue Screen of Death" and write down the error code.
- [Perform an analysis on the dump file created by the BSoD](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263).